# Loop AsyncTask class and fetch Json and store as object in list

Tags: java, android, json, list, object

I want to connect to an Api which returns me JSON values depending on what I enter as GET request. This JSON structure is always exactly the same only the values from these properties differ. All these JSON values then are constructed into a object list and from there be user further in the application.

With help I now have a working code that connects and reads the `JSON` values with `HttpEntity` and stores these in a `new JSONObject`. This object is send to another function where the object gets stripped and then `constructed` into a `Object list` for later use in the Application.

This code is **working**. Except that this Api link only shows 50 results, depending on what was entered as `GET` request. When there are more than 50 results a new page is created which can be accessed by a number at the end of the url. All these pages that could exist (dont have to as its a user search request) have to be added to the object list aswell.

**Question**: How do I loop through the extended `AsyncTask` class with a new url to fetch JSON data from?

I again note that this code **works** for a single page but I can not figure out how to loop through all existing pages and add these to the same object list.

We start in the activity.java

```
String userSearchRequest = search_activity_data.getString("userSearchRequest");
String URL = "http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/" + userSearchRequest + "/";
// example api url:
//http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/Iron/0"
//The last number is the page you are viewing, every 50 results a new page is created. With 51 results there will be a page 0 and 1 to access.

AsyncFetch AsyncFetch = new AsyncFetch(this);
AsyncFetch.setOnResponse(this);
AsyncFetch.execute(URL);
```

From here the URL is passed to the AsyncFetch class to function `doInBackground` as params.

```
public class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    public AsyncFetch(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    private Context context;
    private JSONObject jsonObject;
    private onResponse onResponse;

    public void setOnResponse (onResponse onResponse) {
        this.onResponse = onResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params ) { //Incompatible return type
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        this.onResponse.onResponse(result);
    }

    public interface onResponse {
        public void onResponse(JSONObject object);
    }


}
```

In the `onPostExecute` in the `AsyncFetch` class the object is then send back to the activity.java

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject object) {
        Log.i("gw2Log", object.toString());

        apiRootObject resultClass = new apiRootObject();

        try {
            resultClass.setCount(object.getInt("count"));
            resultClass.setPage(object.getInt("page"));
            resultClass.setLast_page(object.getInt("last_page"));
            resultClass.setTotal(object.getInt("total"));
            JSONArray list = new JSONArray(object.getString("results"));

            for (int i = 0; i < resultClass.getCount(); i++) {
                JSONObject resultsObject = list.getJSONObject(i);
                apiResults temp = new apiResults();
                temp.setData_id(resultsObject
                        .getInt("data_id"));
                temp.setName(resultsObject
                        .getString("name"));
                temp.setRarity(resultsObject
                        .getInt("rarity"));
                temp.setRestriction_level(resultsObject
                        .getInt("restriction_level"));
                temp.setImg(resultsObject
                        .getString("img"));
                temp.setType_id(resultsObject
                        .getInt("type_id"));
                temp.setSub_type_id(resultsObject
                        .getInt("sub_type_id"));
                temp.setPrice_last_changed(resultsObject
                        .getString("price_last_changed"));
                temp.setMax_offer_unit_price(resultsObject
                        .getInt("max_offer_unit_price"));
                temp.setMin_sale_unit_price(resultsObject
                        .getInt("min_sale_unit_price"));
                temp.setOffer_availability(resultsObject
                        .getInt("offer_availability"));
                temp.setSale_availability(resultsObject
                        .getInt("sale_availability"));
                temp.setSale_price_change_last_hour(resultsObject
                        .getInt("sale_price_change_last_hour"));
                temp.setOffer_price_change_last_hour(resultsObject
                        .getInt("offer_price_change_last_hour"));
                resultClass.addObject(temp);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < resultClass.count; i++) {
            Log.i("gw2Log", resultClass.getObject(i).name);

        }

    }
```

From here I can now access the `resultClass` list and loop through all objects and display their properties and values.

How can I make this work for multiple pages with the exact same JSON structure?

EDIT: I have this code which works in c#. It's the exact same project of mine but now in Android java. So the goal is exactly the same but i can't get it working

```
public static RootObject objFromApi_idToName(string spidyApiUrl, int page){
            RootObject rootObject = null;
            RootObject tempRootObject = null;

            do{
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(spidyApiUrl + "/" + page);

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()){
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
                    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    tempRootObject = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonReader);

                    if (rootObject == null){
                        rootObject = tempRootObject;
                    }
                    else{
                        rootObject.results.AddRange(tempRootObject.results);
                        rootObject.count += tempRootObject.count;
                    }
                }
                page++;
            }

            while (tempRootObject != null && tempRootObject.last_page != tempRootObject.page);
            return rootObject;
        }
```

Comment: Try to change `AsyncFetch.execute(URL);` to `AsyncFetch.execute(URL+YourPageNumber);` (e.g: `AsyncFetch.execute(URL+5);` to load the 5th page)

Comment: @Rami I need to automaticly loop through all pages, not do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i don't think that's a good idea what you'r trying to do, because you can have `OutOfMemoryError` if the amount of server data is too big.

Otherwise, this is my suggestion to load all the data:

1) Make two class variable (in your activity), first for the number of pages and second for your counter:

```
private static final int PAGES_NUMBER = 38; // i think last page  is 38 in your api
private int mPagesCounter = 0;
```

2) Add a JSONObject as class variable (in your activity) to save your pages:

```
JSONObject mAllData = new JSONObject();
```

3) Change your `onPostExecute()` to call `onResponse()` only if all pages are loaded:

```
    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            mAllData.put("page"+mPagesCounter, result);// save your current page with "pageX" as key
            mPagesCounter++;

            if(mPagesCounter <= PAGES_NUMBER){// create another task to load next page
                 AsyncFetch AsyncFetch = new AsyncFetch(YourActivity.this);
                 AsyncFetch.setOnResponse(YourActivity.this);
                 AsyncFetch.execute(URL+mPagesCounter);
            } else {// all pages are loaded -> call onResponse() method 
                 this.onResponse.onResponse(mAllData);
            }
        }
```

4) Change `onResponse()` method to handle new json format.

To loop pages you can do it like that:

```
    Iterator it = object.keys();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String)it.next();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonPage = object.get(key);// here you get your page
            // do the rest of stuff with the page
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've only just found time to try this, i've really no clue what is going on here in this code.

Comment: When you call your AsyncTask, it doesn't directly call onResponse() method to pass data, it saves the result (of the current page) and start another task to get the next page... when you reach the last page the task call onResponse() method to pass the result (all pages) to your interface.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask`, as the name suggests, is a good tool when you're trying to perform a single task asynchronously.

What you're trying to do seems to be the job for a `ThreadPool`, which is a tool aimed at handling a queue of tasks using a set number of worker threads (or Executors). You can make each task add the next task into the queue, or queue the whole batch at once.

It's a very powerful pattern.

Official [example here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html) (example is broken into several pages, navigation is at the bottom).